# Jquery submit form without clicking submit button

Tags: jquery

I would like use Jquery to submit a form automatically once I select a user from the dropdown menu. I don't want any submit button to submit the form. How do I do that with Jquery?

I have the code as follows:

```
$table .= "<form method='post' id='change_user'><select name='hpn_user'>";

foreach($hpnusers as $hpnuser){
  $table .= "<option value='". $hpnuser['id'] . "'>" . $hpnuser['first_name'] . "</option>";
}

$table .= "</select><input type='hidden' name='submit' value='1' ></input></form>";
```

Comment: You can add a change event handler to the select element that calls submit() on the form element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User jquery's .change() to recognize the value of the drop has changed and pass in the form to submit.

Ex.

```
$('userDropdown').change(function() {
            $('form').submit(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

User jQuery's [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method:

```
$('#change_user').submit();
```

If you want to submit the form once an item from the dropdown is selected, add a `change` handler to the dropdown and place the call to `submit()` within it:

```
$('select[name="hpn_user"]').on('change', function(){
    $('#change_user').submit();
});
```

[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/eXMhL/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method='post' id='change_user' name="change" onChange="javascript:
document.forms['change'].submit()">
```

Another Example:

```
<form action="./" method="GET">
 <div align="center"">
  <select name="state" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option>Choose One To Submit This Form</option>
    <option value="CA">CA</option>
    <option value="VA">VA</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</form>
```

Example using Jquery

```
$('hpn_user').change(function() {

   document.forms["change"].submit();

    });
```

Add Name Attribute in `form`
In my example i am considering `name=change` in your form.

Comment: Usage of inline scripts is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

We Can also try like this:

```
  $("#DropDown").change(function(){
            $("#myform").attr("action", "Your URl/"+attr);
            $("#myform").submit();
  })
```

The attribute value is the optional one....unless you want to post some.

May hope it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a change event to the `select` element that will submit the form on change:

```
$('select[name="hpn_user"]').change(function(){
    $('#change_user').submit();
});
```

`submit` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event,
>   **or trigger that event on an element.**

Answer (score 0):

First you can trigger the event assuming that the form it's called `form1`

```
$('form#form1').trigger('submit');
```

Second you could make an ajax called in the event change of your dropdownlist Assuming that you dropdownlist is called `example`

$('select#example').change(function(){

```
  $.ajax({ 

    //your options
  });
})
```