# Attempting to change text input to option input for state to configure tax

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I am creating a checkout system and I am trying to implement tax into it. My business would qualify for Nexus so I am only going to charge tax in the state I am in. Right now the customer enters in the state they live in by typing in the text. So what I am going to do is turn that input field into an option field and list all of the states. The reason for this is so I can carry the value of the tax and ensure the state was entered correctly.

This follow is how I am planning on doing this. Is this a good way to do this or is there a better way I can do it?

I'm not sure how to carry the value with the option chosen though.

```
$base_price = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
    $product_id = $product['product_id'];
    $base_price += $products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity'];
    $shipping_price += $products[$product_id]['shippingprice'] * $product['quantity'];
    $tax_price += $base_price * $taxvalue[''];
}

$total_price += $base_price + $shipping_price + $tax_price;

$state['Ohio'] = "Ohio";
$state['Virginia'] = "Virginia";

$taxvalue['Ohio'] = 1.065;
$taxvalue['Virginia'] = 1;


<?php

if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
    $info = isset($state[$_POST['check']]) ? $state[$_POST['check']] : 

    "The requested state doesn't exist";
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>State</label>
        <select class="optionbar" name='check'>
            <option value=''>Select a State</option>
            <?php
                foreach(array_keys($state) as $option) {
                    echo "<option value='$option'>$option</option>/n";
                }
             ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
foreach($taxvalue as $key => $val) {
    echo "<option value='$val'>$key</option>/n";
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @akond this does provide an answer, as does the answer I see below mine. Both suggest the same idea, mine just more streamlined.

Comment: @Twisty I tried this, but I'm not sure how to make this work outside of the session. My tax value is not in the db, how can I make this recognize and calculate once a state is selected.

Comment: I read the comments on the other answer too. Need more information to be able to understand what you are trying to accomplish. It's not clear. Can you add an example of the resulting HTML you would like to see?

Answer (score 0):

create an array with index the states and value the tax values

```
$state=array("Ohio"=>"1.065", "Virginia"=>"1", "Joe"=>"43");
```

then go throu the array like this:

```
<select class="optionbar" name='check'>
<option value=''>Select a State</option>
<?php
foreach($state as $key=>$option) {
echo "<option value='$option'>$key</option>/n";
}
?>
</select>
```

dont forget the closing tag of

```
<select></select>
```

i see that you skipped it.

As for the choosen value you can always store this in a session Cookie and look always if it is set. for example:

```
setcookie($state_name, $tax_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
// 86400 = 1 day
```

and read it like

```
$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]
```

if there is one stored , this way you can always know the state and the tax value for the user throughout all the check out process as long as the cookie exists
 read here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

**----UPDATE----**

So assuming you want to do your calcs inside the same file this may help:

```
$state=array("Ohio"=>"1.065", "Virginia"=>"1", "Joe"=>"43");



<form id="form" action="" method="post">//add this
<select class="optionbar" name='check'>
<option value=''>Select a State</option>
<?php
foreach($state as $key=>$option) {
echo "<option name="taxvalue" value='$option'>$key</option>/n";
}
?>
</select>
<button  method="post" id="submit" type="submit">submit</button>//add this too
</form><?--          add this too              -->

<?php

if(isset($_POST['taxvalue'])) {// check if the value exists aka if something has been posted

//do your calculations here
$taxvalue=$_POST['taxvalue']; //get the value and store it to a php local variable
//do your calculations here




}else{

echo 'you have to select a state';//error messege for empty state option
}
?>
```

if you do not want the button to apear use a litle jquery to 'auto submit' the value onstate change:

```
$('#form option[name=taxvalue]').change(function(){
 $('#form').submit();
});
```

Look here:[Jquery submit form without clicking submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503352/jquery-submit-form-without-clicking-submit-button)

Comment: For the session part. Do I need to store it in a session if I do nothing else with the value other than in this page? Or do I have to?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make this work outside of the session. My tax value is not in the db, how can I make this recognize and calculate once a state is selected.

Comment: you can use a submit button inside the form to POST the value and calculate what you want, i will update the answer soon to show you how to get the posted variable.